# Practical training, internship or practice?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, word-difference

I was in Technical Secondary School of Economics and I have worked in some companies but I don't know how should I say:
I have been on training practical/internship or practice? 
Is there any difference between this words?

Comment: You could say that you have worked as a paid or unpaid intern, or that you have held paid or unpaid internships.

Comment: In English, it makes no sense to say **school of economics** at a secondary school level. Usually, what is meant is: business school. What you have is: practical experience [doing something].

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best to make things simple.

> I have work experience in this field.

If appropriate, you can list the work you have done. "Work experience" is the usual term for having practice in a a discipline. I would not try to go anywhere else with a description.

Comment: It's way to simple. Making sentences too simple will show lack of care, try to word it in a better way that shows you actually tried.

Answer (score 0):

These do have different meanings in general use which I will try and cover, but please note that they may also have alternative meanings *in specific fields of work*.

> practical training

The word "practical" is usually used in education or training to mean "hands-on" experience. You could say it is the opposite of learning theory. For example someone training to be a chef may learn theory in a classroom, but then also have *practical* lessons in a kitchen. This is normally part of an educational course.

> internship

An internship is a period of work experience within an organisation. This means that you have gained practical experience doing work for a real company as opposed to just practical exercises in an educational environment. It is a very specific arrangement, so you would not describe a period of work experience as an internship unless the organisation in which you worked viewed it as such. Some educational courses organise much shorter periods of "work experience" but these are not always the same as an internship.

> practice

The word practice does have different meanings. Generally speaking it sounds the less professional of all three here. Practice is progressive, so saying you have "had practice" does not necessarily mean you have reached any particular level of achievement. For example, a 5 year old may practice the guitar. Used incorrectly this could sound very amateurish to a prospective employer. However there are some fields, such as medicine, where "practice" is used to mean actually carrying out the work. I don't have any insight into the world of economics but I don't think that is the case there, unless you know better.